# How to jump into Android Application Development?

Tags: android

I am interested in moving into Android application development but don't know exactly where to start.I have good basics in C++ and VC#.NET and clear with the concepts of OOPS.
Can anyone please guide me how should i jump into android application development and help me with some resources.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must have to learn the `Java language` and some of its Core APIs (java.lang, java.util, java.text, java.io etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Will learn them asap. can you also guide me what after i learn them?

Answer (score 0):

Read Basic of Java, use the followin link

[Java Tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/)

After reading basic of java, then move to Android Development, Refer the following link

[Starting Point for Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

Study it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to download Eclipse and install ADT Plugin inside the Eclipse, run the first "HelloWorld" android project and try to understand the project directory structure.

Check this SO Question:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211193/how-to-learn-developing-android-applications/3211803#3211803
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405695/tutorial-tips-trick-for-android